# Waiting for one callback to be done (to get data) before the other

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to get MedGuideURL to be used in the 2nd callback but it's value is empty.It seems the second callback is always happening before the first one is done. I am thinking of using Promise/Observable but is there an easier way?

```
var qrImage = require('qr-image');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region:'us-west-2'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){

    var path = event.path;
    var drugId = path.replace(/\//g, '');
    var MedGuideURL = "";

    var params = {
    TableName: 'QRCodeInfo',
    Key: {
      "DrugId" : drugId
    }
  };
  docClient.get(params, function(err,data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err,null);
    } else {
      console.log("The data is: "+ data.Item.MedGuideURL); //correct value
      callback(null,data);                                   
      MedGuideURL = data.Item.MedGuideURL;
    }

  });

  callback(null, sendRes(200, MedGuideURL)); //MedGuideURL is empty!
};

const sendRes = (status, body) => {
  //console.log(body);
  const svg_string = qrImage.imageSync(body, { type: 'svg', size: 10 });
  var response = {
    statusCode: status,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "image/svg+xml"
    },
    body: svg_string
  };
  return response;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to first understand `async` behavior.
>
> You have doing callback before method get complete

You can change `get` with promise

Example

**if `sendResis` promise method**

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  var path = event.path;
  var drugId = path.replace(/\//g, '');
  var MedGuideURL = "";

  var params = {
    TableName: 'QRCodeInfo',
    Key: {
      "DrugId": drugId
    }
  };
  docClient.get(params).promise().then((data) => {
    console.log('success' + x);
    console.log("The data is: " + data.Item.MedGuideURL);
    MedGuideURL = data.Item.MedGuideURL;
    return sendRes(200, MedGuideURL); //if sendResis promise method
  }).then((finalResponse) => {
    callback(null, finalResponse);
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      callback(err, null);
    })
};
```

**IF sendResis is not promise :**

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  var path = event.path;
  var drugId = path.replace(/\//g, '');
  var MedGuideURL = "";

  var params = {
    TableName: 'QRCodeInfo',
    Key: {
      "DrugId": drugId
    }
  };
  docClient.get(params).promise().then((data) => {
    console.log('success' + x);
    console.log("The data is: " + data.Item.MedGuideURL);
    MedGuideURL = data.Item.MedGuideURL;
    let finalResponse = sendRes(200, MedGuideURL); //if sendResis not promise method
    return  callback(null, finalResponse);
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      callback(err, null);
    })
};
```

Comment: Thank you it is working. Being new to nodejs, I was not sure how to use promises to deal with asynchronous issues. Your code helps me understand the synthax and flow of it.